# Almacenar contenido de un vector dada una condición (Búsqueda por rango) Java

Tags: java, array

primer post en esta página, quisiera saber ¿cómo debería estructurar esta subrutina de tal manera que al cumplirse la condición que coloco en el if se almacenen en un vector auxiliar para luego imprimir ese vector hasta "cont" (que vendría a ser el número de veces que se cumplió esa condición).

PD: Este método trata de buscar por rango dentro de un vector.

```
public static void printRange(BigInteger arr[], BigInteger lb, BigInteger ub) {
    int n = arr.length;
    BigInteger aux[] = new BigInteger[n];
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int arrchl = arr[i].compareTo(lb);
        int arrchu = arr[i].compareTo(ub);
        if (arrchl == 1 && arrchu == -1) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + aux[i] + "]");
        System.out.print("");
    }

}
```

Output:
El tamaño del vector generado es de 5 casillas
El vector random creado es: 
[33][102][16][90][66]
Rango del nuevo vector está entre 0 y 100
[null][null][null][null]

Y el resultado debería ser en este caso:
[33][16][90][66]

Comment: Para incluir la validación del rango [a,b] en un intervalo cerrado tuve que hacer lo siguiente:
int arrcl = arr[i].compareTo(lb.subtract(uno));
            int arrcu = arr[i].compareTo(ub.add(uno));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del `if`debes guardar el valor comparado en tu array aux, ya que cumple con la condición establecida:

```
...
if (arrchl == 1 && arrchu == -1) {
            aux[cont] = arr[i];  //<----
            cont++;
        }
...
```